# Ant database and configuration manager

Tags: python, ant

Inspired by another thread on here I was wondering if I could have an expert eye passed over this script?

If I run the script with App1, App2 or App3 individually it takes about 3 mins per run.  However when I invoke the ALL option that time increases to an hour.  I'm no doubt managing my memory awfully so any advise would be great.

I'm new to this so getting this far has been good; my customer is happy running the 3 separately but I like to finish things properly.

```
# Get Domain State

import sys,os
from weblogic.management.security.authentication import UserEditorMBean

from time import strftime, sleep
today = strftime('%Y%m%d %H:%M.%S')

#import wlstutility
#wlstutility.initialise(globals())
#from wlstutility import *
#from wlstutility.constructors import *
from java.io import FileInputStream

environment = []
component = []
adminURL = ""
adminServerName = ""
configFile = ""
userKeyFile = ""
userConfigFile = ""
keyFile = ""
adminServersFail = 0
adminServersErrorCapture = []
adminServerRunning = 0
adminServerLog = []
connectToAdminServerFail = 0
setEnvironmentPropertiesFail = 0
managedServersFail = 0
managedServersErrorCapture = []
managedServerRunning = 0
managedServerState = []
otherErrorCount = 0
otherErrorCapture = []
exitCode = 255

def setEnvironmentProperties(environment, component):
    try:
        global setEnvironmentPropertiesFail
        setEnvironmentPropertiesFail = 0
        print "Checking and connecting to " + component
        print strftime('%Y%m%d %H:%M.%S') + " INFO: environment: " + environment
        domainPFile = environment + "/" + component+ ".properties"
        print strftime('%Y%m%d %H:%M.%S') + " INFO: domainPFile: " + domainPFile
        print strftime('%Y%m%d %H:%M.%S') + " INFO: component: " + component
        loadProperties(domainPFile)
        dpInputStream = FileInputStream(domainPFile)
        domainProps = Properties()
        domainProps.load(dpInputStream)
        global configFile
        configFile = "./"+environment+"/"+component+"configFile"
        print strftime('%Y%m%d %H:%M.%S') + " INFO: configFile: " + configFile
        global userConfigFile
        userConfigFile=configFile
        global keyFile
        keyFile = "./"+environment+"/"+component+"keyFile"
        print strftime('%Y%m%d %H:%M.%S') + " INFO: keyFile: " + keyFile
        global userKeyFile
        userKeyFile=keyFile
        global adminUrl
        adminUrl="t3://" + adminListenAddress + ":" + adminListenPort
        print strftime('%Y%m%d %H:%M.%S') + " INFO: adminUrl: " + adminUrl
        global adminServerName
        adminServerName = adminServerName
        global clusterAddress
        clusterAddress = clusterName
        print strftime('%Y%m%d %H:%M.%S') + " INFO: clusterAddress: " + clusterAddress
    except:
        print " FATAL: Could NOT set properties for " + environment + " " + component
        global setEnvironmentPropertiesFail
        setEnvironmentPropertiesFail += 1
        global otherErrorCount
        otherErrorCount += 1
        global otherErrorCapture
        otherErrorCapture.append(" WARNING: Properties Could Not Be Set For " + environment + " " + component)
        global adminServerLog
        adminServerLog.append(environment + ";" + adminServerName + ";" + " " + ';' + " " + ';' + component + ';' + "PROPSNOTFOUND")    


def connectToAdmin():
    try:
        global connectToAdminServerFail
        connectToAdminServerFail = 0
        print strftime('%Y%m%d %H:%M.%S') + " INFO: Connecting to running AdminServer"
        connect(userConfigFile=configFile, userKeyFile=keyFile, url=adminUrl)
        print strftime('%Y%m%d %H:%M.%S') + " INFO: Getting " + adminServerName + " Server Status"
        domainRuntime()
        cd('/ServerRuntimes/' + adminServerName) 
        ss = cmo.getState()
        hs = cmo.getHealthState()
        x = hs.toString().split(',')[1].split(':')[1] 
        print strftime('%Y%m%d %H:%M.%S') + " INFO: " + adminServerName + ': ' + ss + ': ' + x
        cd('../..')
        global adminServerLog
        adminServerLog.append(environment + ";" + adminServerName + ";" + ss + ';' + x + ';' + component + ';')


    except:
        global connectToAdminServerFail
        connectToAdminServerFail += 1
        print strftime('%Y%m%d %H:%M.%S') + " FATAL: Cannot connect to " + adminUrl + " ensure property files are correct"
        global adminServersErrorCapture
        adminServersErrorCapture.append(environment + ";" + adminUrl + ";" + component)
        global adminServerLog
        adminServerLog.append(environment + ';' + adminServerName + ';' + "" + ';' + " " + ';' + component + ';' + 'FAILEDCONNECTADMIN')


def findManagedServers():
    print strftime('%Y%m%d %H:%M.%S') + " INFO: Finding Managed Servers"
    try:
        global findManagedServerFail
        findManagedServerFail = 0
        domainConfig()
        print "CD to cluster" + clusterAddress
        cd('Clusters/' +clusterAddress)
        global managedServers
        managedServers=cmo.getServers()
        global numberofManagedServers
        numberofManagedServers=`len(managedServers)`
        print strftime('%Y%m%d %H:%M.%S') + " INFO: Found " + numberofManagedServers + " Managed Servers"

    except:
        global findManagedServerFail
        findManagedServerFail += 1
        print strftime('%Y%m%d %H:%M.%S') + " FATAL: Error navigating DomainConfig MBean tree for managed servers"      
        global managedServerState
        managedServerState.append(environment + ';' + "Managed Server Name NOT Found" + ';' + " " + ';' + " " + ';' + component + ';' + "FAILEDMSMBEAN")




def getManagedServerState():
    domainRuntime()
    for servers in managedServers:
        managedServerName=servers.getName()
        print "Checking MS State of " + managedServerName
        try:
            print strftime('%Y%m%d %H:%M.%S') + " INFO: Getting " + managedServerName + " Server Status"
            cd('/ServerRuntimes/' + managedServerName) 
            ss = cmo.getState()
            hs = cmo.getHealthState()
            x = hs.toString().split(',')[1].split(':')[1] 
            print strftime('%Y%m%d %H:%M.%S') + " INFO: " + managedServerName + ': ' + ss + ': ' + x
            cd('../..')
            global managedServerState
            managedServerState.append(environment + ';' + managedServerName + ';' + ss + ';' + x + ';' + component + ';')


        except:
            print strftime('%Y%m%d %H:%M.%S') + " WARNING: " + managedServerName + " could NOT be contacted please investigate!"
            global managedServersFail
            managedServersFail =+ 1
            global managedServersErrorCapture
            managedServersErrorCapture.append(environment + ';' + managedServerName + ';' + " " + ';' + " " + ';' + component)
            global managedServerState
            managedServerState.append(environment + ';' + managedServerName + ';' + " " + ';' + " " + ';' + component + ';' + "FAILEDCONNECTMANAGED")
    if managedServersFail == numberofManagedServers:
        print strftime('%Y%m%d %H:%M.%S') + " FATAL: No Managed Servers Can Be Contacted in Cluster " + clusterAddress
        exitCode = -1

def internalServiceBus(component):
    if component == INTSB:
        try:
            domainRuntime()
            for server in serverNames:
                cd ('ServerRuntimes/intsb_ms1/JMSRuntime/intsb_ms1.jms/JMSServers/idecideserver_1/Destinations/idecideresources!idecideserver_1@idecide.commonerror')
        except:
            print strftime('%Y%m%d %H:%M.%S') + " Warning: Unable to connect to " + managedServerName
            managedServersFail += 1
            managedServersErrorCapture.append(server + " Unable to navigate domainRuntime MBean tree, please investigate")
            exitCode = -1

def exitDomainState():
    print ""
    print "---------------------------------------------------"
    print " Domain State Checks Complete"
    print "---------------------------------------------------"
    print ""
    print ""
    print "The Following Services are Running Without Issue:"
    print ""
    for smallsEnv in environments:

        print smallsEnv

        for smallsComponents in components:
            for keys in adminServerLog:
                key=keys.split(";")
                if key[0] == smallsEnv:
                    if key[4] == smallsComponents:
                        if key[5] != "FAILEDCONNECTADMIN" and key[5] != "PROPSNOTFOUND":
                            printcount = 0
                            while printcount < 1:
                                print "-" + smallsComponents
                                print "--Administration Server"
                                printcount += 1
                        if key[2] == "RUNNING":
                            print "    INFO: Weblogic Server " + key[1] + " is currently " + key[2] + " " + key[3]

            global msprintcount
            msprintcount = 0
            for keys in managedServerState:
                key=keys.split(";")
                if key[0] == smallsEnv:
                    if key[4] == smallsComponents:
                        if key[5] != "FAILEDCONNECTMANAGED":
                            while msprintcount < 1:
                                print "--Managed Servers"
                                global msprintcount
                                msprintcount += 1
                        if key[2] == "RUNNING":
                            print "    INFO: Weblogic Server " + key[1] + " is currently " + key[2] + " " + key[3]

        print "---------------------------------------------------"
    print ""
    print ""
    print "---------------------------------------------------"
    print "The Following Services have issues :"
    print "---------------------------------------------------"
    print ""    

    for smallsEnv in environments:
        global smallscount
        smallscount = 0
        for smallsComponents in components:
            for keys in adminServerLog:
                key=keys.split(";")
                if key[0] == smallsEnv: 
                    if key[4] == smallsComponents:
                        if key[5] == "FAILEDCONNECTADMIN" or key[5] == "PROPSNOTFOUND" or key[2] != "RUNNING" or key[3] != "HEALTH_OK":
                            printcount = 0
                            while printcount < 1:
                                while smallscount < 1:
                                    print smallsEnv
                                    smallscount += 1
                                print "-" + smallsComponents
                                print "--Administration Server"
                                printcount += 1
                        if key[5] == "FAILEDCONNECTADMIN":
                            print "    FATAL: Could NOT Connect to " + key[1] + " Administration Server - Check Properties and/or server logs"
                        if key[5] == "PROPSNOTFOUND":
                            print "    FATAL: Properties NOT found for " + smallsComponents + " Please Check Files"
                        if (key[2] != "RUNNING") and `len(key[2])` < 1:
                            print "    WARNING: Weblogic Server " + key[1] + " is communicating but has a state of " + key[2] + " check log files"
                        if (key[3] != "HEALTH_OK") and `len(key[2])` < 1:
                            print "    WARNING: Weblogic Server " + key[1] + " is " + key[2] + " but has a bad health status"

            global msprintcount
            msprintcount = 0
            for keys in managedServerState:
                key=keys.split(";")
                if key[0] == smallsEnv:
                    if key[4] == smallsComponents:
                        if key[5] == "FAILEDMSMBEAN" or key[5] == "FAILEDCONNECTMANAGED" or key[2] != "RUNNING" or key[3] != "HEALTH_OK":
                            while msprintcount < 1:
                                while smallscount < 1:
                                    print smallsEnv
                                    print "-" + smallsComponents
                                    smallscount += 1
                                print "--Managed Servers"
                                global msprintcount
                                msprintcount += 1
                        if key[5] == "FAILEDCONNECTMANAGED":
                            print "    FATAL: Could NOT Connect to Managed Server: " + key[1] + " - server state " + key[2] + " check console and logfiles"
                        if key[5] == "FAILEDMSMBEAN":
                            print "    ERROR: Failed to traverse Managed Server MBEAN Tree in domainConfig() - Check Admin server health and properties, this error can also be generated if the domain has NO managed servers"
                        if (key[2] != "RUNNING") and `len(key[2])` < 1:
                            print "    WARNING: Weblogic Server " + key[1] + " is communicating but has a state of " + key[2] + " check log files"
                        if (key[3] != "HEALTH_OK") and `len(key[2])` < 1:
                            print "    WARNING: Weblogic Server " + key[1] + " is " + key[2] + "but has a bad health status"
        global smallscount
        smallscount = 0
    disconnect()
    exit()
try:
    environment=sys.argv[1]
    component=sys.argv[2]
    print "Environment " +  environment
    if environment == "App1":
        global environments
        environments = []
        environments.extend(["SM1","SM2","SM3",])
        global components
        components = []
        components.extend(["IL2CMS","IL2FORMS","IL2PORTAL","IL3FORMS","IL3COMMS",])
    if environment == "App2":
        global environments
        environments = []
        environments.extend(["SM1","SM2","SM3","SM4",])
        global components
        components = []
        components.extend(["BPM","INTSB","EXTSB","OPA","VRD","BULKINTSB","BULKEXTSB",])
    if environment == "App3":
        global environments
        environments = []
        environments.extend(["SM1","SM2","SM3",])
        global components
        components = []
        components.extend(["ETL","PORTAL","SB","SP",])  
    if environment == "ALL":
        global environments
        environments = []
        environments.extend(["SM1","SM2","SM3","SM4"])
        global components
        components = []
        components.extend(["IL2CMS","IL2FORMS","IL2PORTAL","IL3FORMS","IL3COMMS","BPM","INTSB","EXTSB","OPA","VRD","BULKINTSB","BULKEXTSB","ETL","PORTAL","SB","SP",])  
    for environmentState in environments:
        print "Checking and connecting to " + environmentState
        for componentState in components:
            environment = environmentState
            component = componentState
            setEnvironmentProperties(environment, component)
            if setEnvironmentPropertiesFail == 0:
                connectToAdmin()
                if connectToAdminServerFail == 0:
                    findManagedServers()
                    if findManagedServerFail == 0:
                        getManagedServerState()
            disconnect()
#               if setEnvironmentPropertiesFail > 0:
#                   global managedServerState
#                   managedServerState.append(environment + ';' + managedServerName + ';;;' + component + ';' + "FAILED")

    exitDomainState()

#   environments = [environment]
#   components = [component]
#   setEnvironmentProperties(environment, component)
#   connectToAdmin()
#   findManagedServers()
#   getManagedServerState()
#   exitDomainState()
#   exit()

finally:
    exit()
```

Comment: Where is the profiler output?

Answer (score 2):

This may not account for everything, but notice that you're doing more work in `ALL` than in the sum of the other options.

See `App1` for example - you iterate over [SM1, SM2, SM3] x [IL2CMS, IL2FORMS, IL2PORTAL, IL3FORMS, IL3COMMS] which is 15 combinations of (environment, component) in total.

Now, look at `ALL`. Every component is checked in *every* environment, so now the five components from `App1` are also combined with SM4, which they never were before. That's 5 more iterations for the `App1` components that you don't run for `App1` alone.

Similarly, `App3`'s four components are evaluated for `SM4`, which they weren't before.

That's only nine more combinations in total than running the three options sequentially - perhaps those combinations take more time to complete because they don't really exist, and the connections time out?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The connections do exist it just slows down as the script progresses.  

I'll try changing the ALL segment to break the array into smaller chunks.

Thanks!
Dave

Comment: I'd suggest breaking the environment-specific branches out into functions returning a flat list of `(environment,component)` tuples: then the `ALL` branch can just call each function and cat the lists together

Answer (score 0):

`except` followed by nothing is like running with scissors: any kind of error will be 'swallowed' (deleted forever) and you will never know if you have a bug, instead do:

```
try:
    some_code
except ExpectedException:
    other_code
```